# What is the coefficient of $x^4$ in the expansion of $(2x−1)^7$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

What is the coefficient of $x^4$ in the expansion of $(2x−1)^7$?

I believe that I am to expand to the power of 7 and then chose the value for which x is to the power of 4.

so:

> $7C3(2x^4)(-1)^3$

Which ends up to be:

> $-70x^4$

But that answer is incorrect. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Raise the coefficients to their respective powers. So, it is ${7\choose 3}\cdot(2x)^4\cdot(-1)^3$

Comment: It's $(2x)^4$ not $2x^4$.

Comment: oh, so it is 16x^4?

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: The final value is $-560x^4$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the binomial theorem and you will find: $-560x^{4}$.
The binomial theorem is: $$\left(a+b\right)^n=\sum _{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}a^{\left(n-i\right)}b^i$$

Comment: The OP has that already; that's how he got his first formula. (${}_7C_3$ is an alternative notation for the binomial coefficient $\binom 73$). His problem was that he didn't plug $a=2x$ correctly into the $a^{n-i}$ part.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative proof is by using Taylor polynomial expansion.

Let $$f(x) = (2x-1)^7$$

The coefficient of $x^4$ is $$\frac {f^{(4)}(0)}{4!} = -560 $$

Comment: Is that any easier without a computer though?

Comment: Derivatives are easy to find without a computer. Do  you want me to show the derivatives in my solution.

Comment: @Sudix: In this case the derivatives are fairly easy to do because one of the derivatives in the chain rule happens to be constant, so the expression doesn't become more complex as you go along.

Comment: Yes indeed. This is an alternative method to the binomial expansion and sometimes it is easier to compute the coefficients this way.

Comment: I have seen Taylor's expansion couple of times, but never really understood how to apply it.

Comment: It is time to learn more about it. The coefficients are found by differentiating your function and dividing by factorial. It is both beautiful and useful.